# Gscript to read gmail attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I wrote a code which reads a .csv file from a Gmail attachment, and writes it to my active Google Sheet.

This script operates correctly the first time, but subsequent executions write old data only. When I re-send the CSV with different values, it still writes old values.

For example : gmail received the below data

```
Name | sal  
Abhi | 400  
Nil  | 600
```

This will successfully update on my active sheet.

If I manually delete this mail and receive a new attachment:

```
Name | sal
Jho  | 600
Maik | 500
```

This time, my code will not write the above data, even though the old email has been deleted. It will still write Abhi 400,nil 600.

Below is the code:

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("STUDENT");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); 
  }
}
```

Comment: what are you even talking about?

Comment: Can you please provide your code? Code will speak for itself.

Comment: function importCSVFromGmail() {
  
  var threads = GmailApp.search("STUDENT");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  
  
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    
  }
  
}

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the code in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks all its resloved now .vai the below code thread[0].getmessage().[   thread.getmessage.length -1]

Comment: Yep, you were reading the original message, because you didn't delete it, you moved it to the trash.